# Laptop + External Monitor: Possible to Scale Mouse-crossover Position?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with a 16" screen @ 1366x768 resolution, and a 24" external monitor at 1920x1200 resolution. I'm extending the Windows 7 desktop onto the other screen.

The 24" is the secondary monitor, and is positioned so the bottom of that screen lines up with the bottom of the 16" screen. Currently, if I move the mouse to the top portion of the 24" screen, then move left, the mouse will stop at the edge of the 24" screen until I move it down far enough to get into the range of the 16" screen.

So that's all pretty standard; but I'm wondering if there's any software out there that will allow me to "scale" the mouse-crossover position, such that if I'm at the TOP of the 24" screen and move left, the mouse will cross to the TOP of the 16" screen, whereas if I'm at the BOTTOM of the 24" screen, crossing over will position the mouse at the BOTTOM of the 16" screen. So then, if the mouse cursor is on the 24" screen at (x,y) position (10,600), and I move 20 pixels left, the mouse is now on the 16" screen at position (1356,384).

Anyone know of such a solution??

*Note: I also use Ubuntu, so if there's a solution to this for X, but not Windows, I'd be interested in that also.*

Comment: +1; I'd like to see similar solutions for Mac, too. My Windows monitors are the same size, but my MacBook gets hooked up to all manner of differently-sized screens and I'd *love* to see a solution for that platform, as well as Windows and Linux.